# What is the double-period operator in MATLAB followed by a division operator (../)?

Tags: matlab

I am analyzing some MATLAB code where there is the following operator: `../`. I cannot find any documentation on this operator explaining what it does. Can anyone explain it to me?

```
 sp(it,:) = (ww).*(1../sigt).*exp(-.5*(e(it,:).^2)./(sigt.^2))*srpfrac);
```

Just being pedantic.

Comment: That's `1.0./sigt` they just left off the `0`

Comment: Thanks! Feel kind of dumb haha.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/2586922) :-P

Comment: Also, impressively if you look at the syntax highlighting of the code, you'll see that the first `.` is red just like the `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `../` operator, the first `.` is associated with the `1` indicating a [radix point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point) and the `./` is [element-wise division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html). This was likely written by someone who is used to Python where all numbers are considered integers unless the radix point is explicitly included. The more verbose equivalent is:

```
1.0 ./ sigt
```

In your case, the `0` has been omitted as it is optional.

To improve readability and future confusion, I would just change it to the following.

```
1 ./ sigt
```